# Mutating Redux Store Array of Objects in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, store

My store consists of an array of objects as such:

```
const INIT_STATE = {
  users:[],
  contacts : []
};
```

And i am attempting to change mutate the store array like this:

```
const App = (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BLOCK_CONTACT:
      state.contacts.map((contact, index) => {

        if (contact._id === action.payload) {
          state.contacts[index].status = "blocked;
          return {
            ...state
          };
        }
        return {
          ...state
        };
      })
      return {
        ...state
      };
   }
}
```

But my store value does not change.
When i log the state value after the if statement, i get the correct state values but my state is not being updated. I think it might have  something to do with my `return` statement but at this point i have tried different variations with no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i think that reducer should not mutate state. And this should be done with action not in switch from reducer.

Comment: As @shivetay said, your reducer is not correct and you should define store of redux and correct reducers for it. see [here](https://redux.js.org/usage/configuring-your-store)

Comment: Could you provide an example instead?

Comment: And as my question suggests, i am trying to mutate the store which then changes the state with mapStateToProps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Incase anyone else that might need help on this, here is the code...

```
const App = (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BLOCK_CONTACT:
      var list = state.contacts.map(contact => {
        var blockList = {
          ...contact
        };

        if (contact._id === action.payload) {
          blockList.status = 1;
        }
        return blockList;
      })
      return {
        ...state,
        contacts: list
      };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if your app is in the start of the way, you can read [this](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-jotai-state-management/) article about jotai state management ([Jotai](https://jotai.org/))